# Backup and restore Keychain

Tags: backup, macos, restore, keychain, install

I want to reinstall my system so I would have fresh Mac OS X. Is there a way how can I export/backup all content of my Keychain Access (all certificates and other things) and then after reinstall to import it back? Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Save the content of the keychain folder `/Users/[UserName]/Library/Keychains` on an external drive or in the cloud.
2. After the reinstall, replace the contents of `/Users/[UserName]/Library/Keychains` with the data you saved in step 1.
3. You may need to do a reboot, for all changes to go into effect.

(Some of your keys may already be saved in iCloud through iCloud Keychain)